# Closed form for CRT solution using Euler $\phi\,$ (totient)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Can anyone show some hints to this? If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)}=1 \pmod{ab}$.
I know that $a^{\phi(b)}=1 \pmod{b}$, and similarly, $b^{\phi(a)}=1 \pmod{a}$, but then how do I combine the work so that I get the result I need?
Thanks!

Comment: You have posted 8 questions so far, accepted none of them, and been posting for a week. Could you please write your posts as questions rather than orders? And if you find that your previous questions have been satisfactorily answered, then please consider accepting the answer you find most helpful. See the FAQ on accepting answers.

Comment: Thanks for going through your old posts, and thank you for editing the question. Instead of looking at each summand separately, consider the *entire* sum $a^{\phi(b)}+b^{\phi(a)}$ modulo $a$ and modulo $b$, as Bill and I both suggested below.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Thank you a lot for guiding me within this wonderful math forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's  $\,(0,1) + (1,0) = (1,1)\,$ in $\,\mathbb Z/a \times \mathbb Z/b\,,\,$ i.e. $\,a^{\phi(b)}\to (0,1)\,$ being $\,0\bmod a\,$ & $\,1\bmod b$

This is the special case $\,\alpha = \beta = 1\,$ in the following form of the Chinese Remainder Theorem:

**Theorem (CRT, via Euler $\phi$)** $\,\,$ If $\,a,\,b\,$ are coprime integers then

$$x\equiv \alpha\!\!\!\pmod{\!a},\,\ x\equiv\beta\!\!\!\pmod{\!b}\iff x\,\equiv\,\alpha\,b^{\phi(a)}+ \beta\,a^{\phi(b)}\!\!\! \pmod{\!ab}\qquad$$

**Proof** $\,(\Leftarrow)\,\,$ Immediate from $\,b^{\phi(a)}\equiv 1\pmod{\!a},\,$ $a^{\phi(b)}\equiv 1\pmod{\!b},\,$ $\,\phi(n)\ge 1$.

$\,(\Rightarrow)\,\,$ The solution is unique $\!\bmod ab\,$ since if $\,x',\,x\,$ are solutions then $\,x'\equiv x\,$ mod $\,a,b\,$ therefore $\,a,\,b\,|\,x'-x\,\Rightarrow\,ab\,|\,x'-x\,\,$ [since](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8286/242) $\,\,a,\,b\,$ coprime $\,\Rightarrow\,{\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab\,.\ \ $ **QED**

Comment: Can you think of another formula given some *other* known multiplicative arithmetic function such as $\omega(n)$?

Answer (score 13):

Verify the congruence holds modulo $a$ and modulo $b$. Then use the fact that if $a|k$, $b|k$, and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $ab|k$.