# Prove that $x \equiv a \pmod{de}$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that if $d$ and $e$ are relatively prime and $a$ is an integer, then \begin{align*}x & \equiv a \pmod{d}\\x &\equiv a \pmod{e}\end{align*} implies $x \equiv a \pmod{de}$.

The two given congruences imply $x = (a+dk_1) = (a+ek_2)$. How do we use this to prove the statement?

Comment: You have $d \mid (x-a)$ and $e \mid (x-a)$. Thus $lcm (e,d) \mid (x-a)$. But the latter is $ed$ under your assumption. I think this ought to have been ask many times already.

Comment: @quid How do $d \mid (x-a)$ and $e \mid (x-a)$ imply $\text{lcm}(e,d) \mid (x-a)$?

Comment: continue.... $dk_1 - ek_2 = 0$ so $dk_1 = e_k_2$. So $dk_1/e$ is a whole number but as $d$ and $e$ are relatively prime and have no factors in common, $k_1/e = k_3$ is a whole number.  So $x = a + dek_3$. and $x \equiv a \mod de$.

Comment: If a|c and b|c then $\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}|c$ and $\lcm(a,b) = \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$.  Consider the prime factors and powers of $a$ and $b$.  They each divide c, so the least common multiples of the prime factors and powers must also divide c.

Comment: $(x-a)$ is a multiple of both $d$ and  $e$ thus it is  a *common* multiple of $e$ and $d$. Every common multiple of $e$ and $d$ is a multiple of the least common multiple, almost by definition.

Comment: @quid d'oh.  That is *sooo* much more straightforward than what I said.

Comment: Indeed quid's comment points out that [this Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8243/if-gcda-b-1-x-equiv-0-pmoda-x-equiv-0-pmodb-then-prove-that?rq=1) resolves the current one if $x-a$ is substituted for $x$.

Comment: $d,e\mid n\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm lcm}(d,e)\mid n.\ $ Yours is special case $\,n = x-a\,$ and $\,\gcd(d,e) = 1,\,$ so $\,{\rm lcm}(d,e) = de.\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(a+dk_1) = (a+ek_2) \Rightarrow dk_1 = ek_2.$$
Since $d$ and $e$ are coprime, then $k_1 = e q$ and $k_2 = d q$ for some $q$. This means that:

$$x = a+dk_1 = a + deq.$$

Answer (score 0):

continue.... $dk_1 - ek_2 = 0$ so $dk_1 = ek_2$. So $dk_1/e$ is a whole number but as $d$ and $e$ are relatively prime and have no factors in common, $k_1/e = k_3$ is a whole number.  So $x = a + dek_3$. and $x \equiv a \mod de$.

===

postscript: Let $e = \prod p_i^{a_i}; p_i$ prime.  Let $d \prod q_i^{b_i}; q_i$ .  As $e$ and $d$ are coprime the $p_i$ and the $q_i$ are distinct.

You have $x = (a - ek_1) = (a - k_1\prod p_i^{a_i})= (b - ek_2) = (b - k_2\prod q_i^{q_i})$

So $k_1\prod p_i^{a_i} = k_2\prod q_i^{q_i}$

So $\prod q_i^{b_i}|k_1$ and $\prod p_i^{a_i}|k_2$.

So $x = (a - k_3*\prod  q_i^{b_i} \prod p_i^{a_i}) = (a- k_3de)$