# Does the formula $\sqrt{ 1 + 24n }$ always yield prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, elementary-number-theory

I did some experiments, using C++, investigating the values of $\sqrt{1+24n}$.

```
 n: 1 -> 5
 n: 2 -> 7
 n: 5 -> 11
 n: 7 -> 13
 n: 12 -> 17
 n: 15 -> 19
 n: 22 -> 23
 n: 35 -> 29
 n: 40 -> 31
 n: 57 -> 37
 n: 70 -> 41
 n: 77 -> 43
 n: 92 -> 47
```

I wonder,  if 
$$\sqrt{1+24n}$$ 
is an integer, will it also be a prime?

Is there any interesting theory about this formula?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: Do you mean, does it give a prime whenever it gives an integer? (Obviously, it doesn't always give a prime because it doesn't always give an integer).

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Yes, that what I tried to say.

Comment: @Chan: I'm not criticizing here, just curious: why did you skip $n = 26$ in your experiments?

Comment: @Pete L.Clark: My foor-loop run from 1->100, and it only checks for prime.

Comment: But many of your $n$ are not primes, so why did you skip 26?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about $n=26$?

In general, take a composite number of the form $12k+1$ and take $n = k + 6k^2$ to arrive at a contradiction for your statement.

For instance,

$k=2 \Rightarrow n=26 \Rightarrow \sqrt{1+24n} = 25$

$k=4 \Rightarrow n=100 \Rightarrow \sqrt{1+24n} = 49$

$k=7 \Rightarrow n=301 \Rightarrow \sqrt{1+24n} = 85$

and so on.

There are infinite composite numbers of the form $(12k+1)$ which gives infinite counterexamples to your claim.

Your observation though is a nice one, since $24 | (p^2-1)$, $\forall \text{ primes } p > 3$. So you will find that all the primes $>3$ can be written as $\sqrt{1+24n}$.

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: so what form could yield prime?

Comment: @Chan: What form of what?

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: Sorry for being vague. I mean the the form of `n`.

Comment: @Chan: If you want what form of $n$ will yield you prime, that might be a difficult question to answer. You can of course find what form of $n$ will yield an integer.

Comment: @Chan: Your observation though is a nice one, since $24 | (p^2-1)$, $\forall p > 3$. So you will find that all the primes occur as part of $\sqrt{1+24n}$

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: Thanks, that's what I thought too, since those generated numbers above, from 1->100, did not form any pattern.

Comment: @Chan: Given that every prime number is spanned by the sequence, to know what values of $n$ yield a prime is equivalent to knowing the pattern of primes.

Comment: @InterestedQuest: Multiplying any given number of primes and adding one to it will actually almost always NOT give a prime. If the list doesn't include 2, then the product will be odd, and hence adding 1 will be even meaning 2 divides it and hence is not prime.

Comment: @InterestQuest: Even if the list were to include $2$, it will fail. $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 + 1 = 30031 = 59 \times 509$

Comment: Sorry, I made a common mistake based on a proof that number of primes is infinite.

Comment: Small note $24 | (n^2-1)$, $\forall \text{ odd } n > 3$

Answer (score 8):

**HINT** $\rm\: \mod\ 24\::\ \ x^2 \equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ (5x)^2 \equiv 1\:,\ $ but $\rm\:5\:x\:$ is prime iff $\rm\: x= \pm1$

Note that this yields a general *structural* reason explaining why such integers can't all be primes. Namely, the integers you describe are simply those integers that, when reduced modulo $24\:,$ yield square roots of $1\:.\:$ But such roots are closed under multiplication: $\rm\ x^2\equiv 1,\ y^2\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ (xy)^2\equiv 1\:.\:$ But primes are *not* closed under multiplication. For example, one can take any of your prime solutions and multiply them to obtain a composite solution, e.g. $\rm\ 5^2 = 25,\: \ 5\cdot 7 = 35\:,\:$ etc.

Notice that there are precisely $8\:$ square-roots of $\rm 1\ (mod\ 24)\ $ viz. $\rm \pm 1,\:\pm 5,\:\pm 7,\: \pm 11\:,\:$ corresponding (by $\rm CRT$) to the product of the two roots $\rm\ \pm 1\ (mod\ 3)\ $ times the four roots $\rm\ \pm 1,\: \pm 3\ (mod\ 8)\:.\:$ Note that these are precisely the congruence classes of all the integers coprime to $\:3\:$ and $\rm\:2\:,\:$ which includes *all* primes $> 3$. This explains your empirical observations above. The key observation, that $\rm\ x^2\equiv 1\ (mod\ 24)\ \iff\ x\:$ is coprime to $\:6\:,\:$ is nothing but a very special case computation of Carmichael's generalization of Euler's phi-function - see my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855/for-any-prime-p-3-why-is-p2-1-always-divisible-by-24/910#910) for details.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. $\sqrt{1+24*381276} = 3025 = 605 * 5$

There are many such formulars which seem to yield only primes, but most of them aren't.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. There are many examples, including infinite series, and polynomials in several variables all of whose positive values are prime numbers.

Comment: Changed. I thought it's very difficult or impossible to find a prime generating function which only yields primes. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Look up this wikipedia page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Formula_based_on_a_system_of_Diophantine_equations

Comment: Uhhh... That's difficult. Thanks for this link.

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{1+24\cdot 26} = \sqrt{625} = 25$!

$$\sqrt{1+24\cdot n} = x$$

$${1+24\cdot n} = x^2$$

$$ n = \dfrac{x^2 -1}{24}$$

So if $x=25$, $\dfrac{x^2 -1}{24}$ is an integer.

Comment: I read the 25! as 25 factorial initially.  I was quite confused ;-).

Answer (score 1):

(p-1)(p+1) must be divisible by 2 times 4 if p is an odd integer (since p-1 and p+1 are then "consequtive even numbers" so both are divisible by 2, and one of them is even divisible by 4). If p is not divisible by 3, then one of the numbers p-1 or p+1 must be divisible by 3. Thus for any odd integer p which is not divisible by 3, the product (p-1)(p+1) must be divisible by 2*4*3=24. So for ANY odd integer p not divisible by 3 there exists some integer n (depending on p) such that p^2-1=24 n. So... but you can fill in the blanks now, n'est-ce pas?

Answer (score 0):

take n=$24k^2$+$2k$  , $\Rightarrow \sqrt{1+24n}=24k+1$

24k+1, is composite infinitely, to give one such case..
if $k=24^{2r}$ r=0,1,2,3... then 25 divides $24k+1$ always

it follows, for $n$=$24^{4r+1}$+$(2.24^{2r})$ , r=0,1,2... the value $\sqrt{1+24n}$ is divisible by 25, and hence definitely not prime.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=\sqrt{1+24n}\iff x^2=1+24n\iff x\text{ is an odd number not divisible by }3$$

Answer (score -3):

Right ! I've proven recently this formula which at least englobes all prime numbers for sure. until now I didn't find a prime number that is not written as √24n+1.