# prove that $[5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]$ are the only possible variants of the remainders (read context) when dividing the prime number $p$ by 24

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

The problem is following:

> Given that $p$ is a prime number, $p > 3$. Prove that $(p^2 - 1)$  is divisible by $24$.

I started writing down the possible remainders of dividing $p$ by $24$ and got the following row: 
${5; 7; 11; 13; 17; 19; 23}$

But am i even right at this point? If i am how do i prove that these are the only possible remainders?

Comment: There is a much more efficient proof. Note that if $p-1$ is a multiple of $3$ then $p+1$ is, and if $p-1$ is not a multiple of $4$, $p+1$ is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For any prime $p>3$, why is $p^2-1$ always divisible by 24?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855/for-any-prime-p-3-why-is-p2-1-always-divisible-by-24)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed that $1$ can be a remainder too (take $p=73$ or $p=97$, for instance). All other elements of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,23\}$ are muliples of $2$ or of $3$. Since $p$ is prime and $24$ is a multiple of both $2$ and $3$, no such number can be the remainder of the division of $p$ by $24$, since that would make $p$ a multiple of $2$ or of $3$.