# Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $m = 2p$. Prove that $a^{m−1} ≡ a \pmod{m}$ for all natural numbers $a$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, totient-function

> Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $m = 2p$. Prove that $$a^{m−1} ≡ a \pmod{m}$$ for all
>   natural numbers $a$.

**My attempts**

If $m$ is relatively prime to $a$, then $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod{m}$ so
$$a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{m}$$
$$a^{p}\equiv a\pmod{m}$$
Together implies $a^{2p-1}\equiv a\pmod{m}$ that $a^{m-1}\equiv a\pmod{m}$

If $m$ is not relatively prime to $a$, then exists some prime divisor $d$ such that $d$ divides $a$ and $d$ divides $m$, since $m=2p$ we have $d=2$ or $d=p$
Suppose $d=2$ that $\dots$

Now i'm stucked here, any ideas about how to prove this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the dupe $\,a^p\equiv a\,$ so scaling that by $\,a^{p-1}\,$ yields $\,a^{2p-1}\equiv a^p\equiv a\ \ $

Comment: Or by [this Theorem:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3556393/242) $\ 2p\mid a(a^{\large (p-1)n}-1)$ for all $n\ge 0.\ $ OP is case $\,n=2\ \ \ $

Comment: Or use [Korselt](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/786547/242).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

$a^{m-1}-a=(a^{p}-a)(a^{p-1}+1)$

According to Fermat's little theorem, $p|a^{p}-a$. In addition, $a^{p}-a$ is divisible by $2$.

Since $p$ is an odd prime, $2p|a^{m-1}-a$ aka $m|a^{m-1}-a$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Nice answer +1.  Isn’t $a^p-a$ always divisible by $2$?

Comment: Well yes haha, thanks.