# Prove by induction that $13n^{13} + 11n^{11}$ is divisible by $24$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, induction, divisibility

I am currently tackling this question and I am stuck.

I have completed proven the base case where $P(1) = 13 + 11 = 24$ and $24\mid24$, hence base case is true.

Then I assume $P(k)$ to be true for some integer $k$, where $(24 \mid 13k^{13} + 11k^{11})$

Then I proceed on proving

$P(k+1) \mod 24$

$= 13(k+1)^{13}  + 11(k+1)^{11}  \mod 24$

$= (k+1)^{11} \cdot[13(k+1)^2 + 11]  \mod 24$

$= (k+11)^{11} \cdot [13k^2 + 26k + 24]   \mod 24$

Then I am very stuck here, as I don't know how do I remove $24$ from the equation; can I just remove $24$ from the equation since '24 will just mod 24 = 0' ?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The first thing you should do is type out all your math in MathJax, it makes it clearer and more people will see your post. As for the question : the best way to use the induction hypothesis would be to consider the difference of $13(k+1)^{13} + 11(k+1)^{11}$ and $13k^{13} + 11k^{11}$.

Comment: An alternative method is to show that this expression is divisible by $3$ and also divisible by $8$. Modulo $3$ it is equivalent to $n^{13}-n^{11}=n^{11}(n^2-1)$ which contains the factors $n-1, n, n+1$ one of which must be divisible by $3$. If $n$ is even, the factor $8$ is obvious. So you are left with showing a factor $8$ for $n$ odd and in this case $n^2\equiv 1 \bmod 8$. But I'm guessing this may have been an exercise in induction rather than the tricks of modular arithmetic.

Comment: I like Mark Bennet's comment and feel that it is worth exploring further.  Suppose that you are faced with a similar problem in the future, where you are not necessarily required to use induction.  You would then have the choice between (elegant) algebraic manipulation or (pedestrian) proof by induction.  In such a situation, I would first invest 30 minutes attempting elegance.  If that failed, I would then invest 60 minutes attempting induction.  ...see next comment

Comment: If the induction also failed, I would consider creating a mathSE query, where I provided the **background** of the work (i.e. what theorems or previously solved problems might be pertinent) and also **showed  my work.**  One alternative might be to first try to review/repair your two attempts before posting on mathSE.  Note that this **elegance vs pedestrianism** methodology has general application in math, rather than being limited to congruency problems.

Comment: @MarkBennet exactly my thought when I looked at the problem first!

Comment: I thought the problem was solved through induction but reading all the comments, seems like it is not. My suggestion will be to look at binomial expansion to prove through induction.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you for reminding.  and Math Lover yes I agree that using modular arithmetic is a more direct and easier way of proving. In fact in my trial, i ended up proving it through prove $13k(k+1)^{11}(k+2)$ divisible by 2,3,4 and thus divisible by 24, induction is hard to use in this case

Comment: This is a special case of a slight generalization of Euler-Fermat - see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know your question is to prove by induction and there is already an answer posted for that. So here is another way -

$13n^{13} + 11n^{11} = 13n^{13} - 13n^{11} + 13n^{11} + 11n^{11} = 13n^{11} (n-1)(n+1) + 24n^{11}$

So, we now just need to prove that $13n^{11} (n-1)(n+1)$ is divisible by 24.

If $n$ is even, either $(n-1), n$ or $(n+1)$ is divisible by $3$ and $n^{11}$ is divisible by $8$.

If $n$ is odd, one of $(n-1), n, (n+1)$ is again divisible by $3$. Also, both $(n-1)$ and $(n+1)$ are even and one of them is divisible by $4$.

So, it is evident that $13n^{13} + 11n^{11}$ is divisible by $24$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: That is nicely done.

Comment: Thank you @MarkBennet

Comment: @Mark In fact its a special case of a twist on ole Euler-Fermat - see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Nice effort, your work got most of the way home.  Using induction, and correcting a typo in the last (modular) equation in your query, you (effectively) reduced the problem to showing that

$[E_1]\; (k + 1)^{(11)} \times [13(k^2 + 2k)] \;\equiv\; 0 \pmod{24}.$

This can be done by showing that the product of the two factors in $E_1$ **must be** both a multiple of 8 and a multiple of 3.

$\underline{\text{multiple of 3}}$

The residue mod 3 of $k$ will be either 0, 1, or 2.

The residue of 2 is immediately disposed of by noting the first factor in $E_1, (k+1)^{(11)}.$

The residue of 0 is immediately disposed of by noting that $k$ divides the 2nd factor in $E_1, 13(k^2 + 2k).$

The residue of 1 is disposed of by noting that 
if $k \equiv 1 \pmod{3},$ 
then $k^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3},$ and 
$2k \equiv 2 \pmod{3}.$

Thus, $k \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \Rightarrow 
(k^2 + 2k) \equiv 0 \pmod{3}.$

$\underline{\text{multiple of 8}}$

$k$ odd is disposed of by noting the first factor in $E_1, (k+1)^{(11)}.$

If $k \equiv 0 \pmod{4},$ 
then $8|k^2$ and $8|2k \Rightarrow 8|(k^2 + 2k).$

The only remaining case is $k \equiv 2 \pmod{4}.$ 
Noting that $(4r + 2)^2 = (16r^2 + 16r + 4),$ this means that 
$k \equiv 2 \pmod{4} \Rightarrow k^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{8}.$

Further, $k \equiv 2 \pmod{4} \Rightarrow 2k \equiv 4 \pmod{8}.$

Thus, $k \equiv 2 \pmod{4} \Rightarrow $ 
$(k^2 + 2k) \equiv (4 + 4) \pmod{8}.$

**Addendum** Reaction to stochasticboy321's subsequent comment. 
Proof by induction.

The short *answer* is : see J.W.Tanner's answer, which I consider a much superior induction approach than my induction approach (below).  Rather than **delete** the remainder of this addendum, I'll leave it in place **for contrast.**

Lemma 1 
Given $k, r, n, a \,\in \mathbb{Z^+},$ with $r \equiv 0 \pmod{a},$ 
then $(k + r)^n \equiv k^n \pmod{a}.$

Proof 
In the binomial expansion of $(k + r)^n - k^n,$ 
$r$ divides every term.

Lemma 2 
For $k \in \{1, 2, 3\}, k^{(13)} - k^{(11)} \equiv 0 \pmod{3}.$

Proof 
By inspection, or you can notice that 
$(k^{(13)} - k^{(11)}) = k^{(11)}(k-1)(k+1).$

Lemma 3 
For $k \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}, k^{(13)} - k^{(11)} \equiv 0 \pmod{8}.$

Proof 
By inspection, or you can (again) notice that 
$(k^{(13)} - k^{(11)}) = k^{(11)}(k-1)(k+1).$

**Note**
I definitely regard the concept in Teresa Lisbon's comment as the *natural*
way to craft a proof by induction.  Unfortunately, I could find no way of doing
this that did not descend into the ugliness of both $(k+1)^{(11)}$ and $(k+1)^{(13)}.$
Given how much easier a non-induction proof is, I am forced to regard the
raw descent into these binomial expansions as **out of bounds.**

I **admit** that my use of Lemma's 2 and 3 above to craft a proof by induction
is highly artificial, since the analysis in these lemmas lends itself so easily
to a non-inductive proof.  However, this is the only **reasonable** way that I
could conjure a proof by induction.

Let $f(n)$ denote $13n^{(13)} + 11n^{(11)} : n \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

**Claim-1** $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, f(n) \equiv 0 \pmod{3}.$

Proof
Since $13 \equiv 1 \pmod{3},$ and $11 \equiv (-1) \pmod{3},$ 
$f(n) \equiv n^{(13)} - n^{(11)} \pmod{3}.$ 
Therefore, Lemma 2 establishes that Claim-1 holds in the 
base cases of $n \in \{1, 2, 3\}.$  
Then, Lemma 1 may be invoked to establish, by induction, 
that Claim-1 holds for all $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

**Claim-2** $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, f(n) \equiv 0 \pmod{8}.$

Proof
Since $13 \equiv 5 \pmod{8},$ and $11 \equiv (-5) \pmod{8},$ 
$f(n) \equiv (5) \times \left[n^{(13)} - n^{(11)}\right] \pmod{8}.$ 
Therefore, Lemma 3 establishes that Claim-2 holds in the 
base cases of $n \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}.$  
Then, Lemma 1 may be invoked to establish, by induction, 
that Claim-2 holds for all $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

Comment: You seem to be running a direct argument, since you're basically directly showing that $13(k+1)^{13} + 11 (k+1)^{11}$ is divisible by $24$. Where are you actually using the induction hypothesis?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 good catch.  I (carelessly) assumed that (adopting my syntax) induction was used to reduce the problem to equation $E_1.$  My bad for not scrutinizing the OP's work closely enough.  Since the OP is specifically required to use induction, I am going to add a pertinent addendum to my query.

Comment: yes in my trial, i ended up proving it directly using modular arithmetic as well, thus i was really wondering how should it actually use the induction hypothesis to prove it

Answer (score 3):

**Claim:**$\;$  $n^{m+2}-n^m$ is divisible by $24$ for $m\ge3$.

Here I prove that claim **by induction**, for $m$ odd, which is all that is needed for this problem.

Base case:  $n^5-n^3=n^3(n+1)(n-1)$ is divisible by $8$ and by $3$.

Induction step:  $n^{k+4}-n^{k+2}\equiv n^{k+2}n^2-n^{k+2}\equiv n^{k}n^2-n^{k+2}=0\bmod24.$

Therefore, $13n^{13}+11n^{11}\equiv13n^{11}+11n^{11}=24n^{11}\equiv0\bmod24$.

Comment: I used induction on the exponent, not the base

Comment: I (also) upvoted, very nice.  In desperation, I considered your approach but couldn't make it work.  In fact, I had to *study* your answer for a few minutes, "wrapping my brain around it", to get it.

Comment: Thank you, @user2661923.  If you have any questions, let me know

Comment: This is [Carmichael's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length)

Answer (score 1):

Put $\, m = 2^3\cdot 3,\ e = 11,\ j = 13,\ k = -11\,$ in the Euler-Fermat generalization below.

**Theorem** $\  $ Suppose that $\ m\in \mathbb N\ $ has the prime factorization $\:m = p_1^{e_{1}}\cdots\:p_k^{e_k}\ $ and suppose that for all $\,i,\,$  $\ \color{#0a0}{e_i\le e}\ $ and $\ \phi(p_i^{e_{i}})\mid f\,$ and $\, j\equiv k\pmod{\!m}.$  Then $\ m\mid \color{#0a0}{a^e}(j\,a^f-k)\ $ for all $\: a\in \mathbb Z.$

**Proof** $\ $ Notice that if $\ p_i\mid a\ $ then $\:p_i^{e_{i}}\mid \color{#0a0}{a^e}\ $ by $\ \color{#0a0}{e_i \le e}.\: $ Else $\:a\:$ is coprime to $\: p_i\:$ so by Euler's phi theorem, $\!\bmod q = p_i^{e_{i}}:\, \ a^{\phi(q)}\equiv 1 \Rightarrow\ a^f\equiv 1\, $ by $\: \phi(q)\mid f\, $ and  [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242), so $\,j\equiv k\,\Rightarrow\, j\,a^f-k\equiv 0.\,$ All prime powers $\, p_i^{e_{i}}\ |\  a^e (ja^f\! - k)\ $ so too does their lcm = product = $m$.

**Examples** $\ $ You can find many illuminating examples in prior questions, e.g. below

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$24\mid a^3(a^2-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408201/242)

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$40\mid a^3(a^4-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/637468/242)

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$88\mid a^5(a^{20}\!-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1316052/242)

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ [$6p\mid a\,b^p - b\,a^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2003925/242)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to express this polynomial in an alternative base, the binomial coefficients one: $$13n^{13}+11n^{11}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{13} a_k\binom{n}{k}$$

Where $n^p = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{p} k!\, S(p,k)\,\binom{n}{k}\text{ and } S$ is the Stirling number of second kind.

And verify that all coefficients are divisible by $24$ :
$$a_k = k!\, \big(13\,S(13,k)+11\,S(11,k)\big)$$

Since $\ k!\ $ is divisible by $24$ as soon as $\ k\ge 4\ $, you only need to verify the first $4$ terms.

- $a_0 = 0$
- $a_1 = 24$
- $a_2 = 128976 = 24\times 5374$
- $a_3 = 22287816 = 24\times 928659$

Yet binomial coefficients being integers too,  the whole expression is divisible by $24$.