# Show that if $p>2 $ is prime, then $8$ divides $p^2 -1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have started it like this

If $p>2$, then $p= 2k+1$ ,

$p^2= 4k^2 +4k+1$,

$p^2 -1 = 4k(k+1)$ ,

But I can't get how to make it divisible by $8$.

Comment: Can you show $k(k+1)$ is even for any integer $k$?

Comment: What if $k$ is even? What if $k$ is odd?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For any prime $p \ge 3$, why is $p^2-1$ always divisible by 24?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855/for-any-prime-p-3-why-is-p2-1-always-divisible-by-24)

Comment: it is not required for p to be prime, this is true for any odd integer $p>2$.

Answer (score 2):

$p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)$ is a product of two even numbers. Since these are consecutive even numbers one of them must be divisible by $4$. So the product is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 0):

To complete your solution, remember that $k (k + 1)$ is always even.

---

We can also do a slightly different alternate solution.

Let, $p=4k-m, ~m\in\left\{1,3\right\}$ then we have,

$$\begin{align}p^2-1&=(4k-m)^2-1\\
&=16k^2-8km+(m^2-1)\end{align}$$

Finally, we observe that if $m:=1,3$ then

$$(m^2-1) \equiv 0 ~(\text{mod}~ 8).$$

Answer (score 0):

Show that if $\;p>\;2$ is prime, then $\;8\;$ divides $\;p^2-1\;.$

**Proof:**

If $\;p>2\;$ is prime, then $\;p= 2k+1\;,\;$ where $\;k\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

moreover,

$p^2=4k^2+4k+1\;,$

$p^2-1=4k(k+1)\;.$

Since $\;k(k+1)\;$ is the product of two consecutive positive integer numbers, it is even, hence

$k(k+1)=2h\;,\;$ where $\;h\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

Consequently,

$p^2-1=4k(k+1)=4\cdot2h=8h\;,$

therefore $\;8\;$ divides $\;p^2-1\;.$